# Which solutions are there to the problem of having too large activations before the softmax (or sigmoid) layer?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, activation-functions, weights, softmax

I'm trying to build a neural network (NN) for classification using only N-bit integers for both the activations and weights, then I will train it with some heuristic algorithm, based only on the NN evaluation.

Currently, I'm using a non-linear activation function for hidden units. Because of its probability interpretation, I am forced to use the softmax (or the sigmoid for 2-class case) for the output layer. However, because of the use of integers, the linear combination of the activations and weights can easily be too large, and this causes a problem to the exponential in the softmax evaluation.

Any solution?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to AI SE. I've edited your post in order to improve its clarity and, in particular, to add a more descriptive title. Let me know if I changed the meaning of your post with my edit. If yes, you can edit again your post to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check out [this question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/a/27698/20538). Generally, you don't need to apply `softmax` and using raw logits leads to better numerical stability.

The numerical issue that you are talking about is well known and dealt with the so-called [`logsumexp` trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp#log-sum-exp_trick_for_log-domain_calculations). This usually is already incorporated in standard NN libraries. For example `keras`
[CategoricalCrossentropy loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CategoricalCrossentropy) can be configured to compute it `from_logits`.